# Why Does Settings And then Dock/Undock Break This Win 7 Desktop Gadget?

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I've narrowed it down to hitting settings, then cancel or okay (no code handling settings events yet) and then attempting to hit the dock button predictably killing the gadget controls. I've tried all suggestions in comments so far including setting the class which I had a feeling was going to break the thing altogether.

What's really bugging me is that it behaves the same way way regardless of arguments fed into the endTransition method or whether the end and beginTrans methods are even there. It's definitely not taking 5 full seconds to transition. That was set at 1 before. Still no difference. Nothing in docs about these transitionTypes that I can find.

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
    <title>Time Tracker Gadget</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
</head>

<body id="gadget">

<!-- pure HTML here, no linked scripts, inline JS, or styles -->

<script type="text/jscript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

JS file:

```
System.Gadget.settingsUI = "settings.html";

var docked = {width:"161px", height:"110px"},
undocked = {width:"295px", height:"390px"},
gadgetEl = document.getElementById('gadget'),

addStyles = function(el,newStyles){
    var elStyle = el.style;
    for(var x in newStyles){ elStyle[x] = newStyles[x]; }
},

swapDockStates = function(){

    System.Gadget.beginTransition();

    if(System.Gadget.docked){
        addStyles(gadgetEl,undocked);
    }
    else {
        addStyles(gadgetEl,docked);
    }

    System.Gadget.endTransition(System.Gadget.TransitionType.morph, 5);

};

System.Gadget.onDock = swapDockStates;
System.Gadget.onUndock = swapDockStates;
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<gadget>
  <name>BigTime Gadget</name>
  <version>1.0.0.0</version>
  <author name="BigTime Software">
    <info url="www.bigtime.net" />
  </author>
  <copyright>&#169; BigTime Software Inc.</copyright>
  <description>Time tracking gadget</description>
  <hosts>
    <host name="sidebar">
      <base type="HTML" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="bigtime.html" />
      <permissions>Full</permissions>
      <platform minPlatformVersion="1.0" />
    </host>
  </hosts>
</gadget>
```

Comment: Try without the begin/end transition bit. I would also recommend using CSS classes.

Comment: Actually, I think it's related to opening settings. Hitting dock/undock after settings will make the UI controls disappear every time.

Comment: Note: I changed the relative path to plain old "settings.html" after seeing other gadgets with the same relative document locations doing that. It was working both ways which strikes me as odd.

Comment: Okay, so this is weird. Killing the sidebar.exe process makes all the frozen gadget instances disappear. Opening up gadgets again brings them all back on the screen with UI working so I can close them all. Settings then dock/undock continues to reliably freeze.

Comment: If somebody could at least point me at some decent non-MS docs on gadgets I'd be much obliged. This is just awful. As far as I can tell some of these setting make no difference whatsoever and yes, I'm certain I'm editing the right files. Pull the right stuff out and everything stops working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh... how embarrassing. Don't link the same JS file with the event handlers and settings location in both your settings file and your gadget file. That would explain some of the apparent behavior of things not mattering whether present or removed. I do wish there was a more in-depth explanation of what's going on in terms of the global scope though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the height of the body to avoid this problem:

```
swapDockStates = function(){

    System.Gadget.beginTransition();

    if(System.Gadget.docked){
        document.body.style.height = '110px';
        addStyles(gadgetEl,undocked);
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.height = '390px';
        addStyles(gadgetEl,docked);
    }
    System.Gadget.endTransition(System.Gadget.TransitionType.morph, 5);
};
```